# SQL JOIN table2 ON table2.value in (table1.value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

I want to perform an inner join on a table, based on it's values, like this:

```
SELECT table2.value FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.key IN (table1.value)
WHERE table1.key = 'test'
```

Something with the in () is not working, the "***in (table1.value)***" is not being interpret as "***in ('1','2')***", it does not show any results.

table1:

```
KEY    VALUE
test   '1','2'
```

table2:

```
KEY    VALUE
1      result1
2      result2
3      result3
```

I know there is a workaround like this, but I'd like to solve this without an additional SELECT..

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.value in (SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE key = 'test')
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks,
Lennart

Comment: You have to use a subquery

Comment: I have an idea! Don't store your values like that in table1. Have one record for each value. The design is inherently flawed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your data structure is simply wrong.  You should not be storing lists of ids in a string.  There are numerous good reasons:

- SQL does not have good string processing functions.
- You should not store integers as strings.
- You should declare proper foreign key relationships.
- Your queries cannot take advantage of indexes or partitioning.

The right solution is one row per key and per value.

However, sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In that case, you can use `like`:

```
SELECT table2.value
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.value LIKE '%''' + t2.key + '''%'
WHERE t1.key = 'test';
```